# Error in importing tensorflow ( python 3.6x )

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip

```
import error tensorflow in python 3.6.0
Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vignesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Vignesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Vignesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Vignesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Vignesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Vignesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\Vignesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Vignesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vignesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Vignesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Vignesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Vignesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Vignesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
>>>
```

Comment: Have you checked the error page you linked?
And tried anything on here? https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22794

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question on this site. In this case, please indicate the context, what you are trying to acheive, what you tried so far to solve your problem ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be because it is installed as a Python 2 package and you're running Python 3 or the opposite.

To specifically install the package for Python 3, try entering this command:

```
pip3 install tensorflow
```

or

```
python3 -m pip install tensorflow
```

To specifically install the package for Python 2, try entering this command:

```
pip2 install tensorflow
```

or

```
python -m pip install tensorflow
```

Comment: `tensorflow` is Python 3 only.